# Does a slice of react redux store state have to be an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm combining the slice of state below (filterText), it's use to filter out results so it only needs to hold a string. Is it possible to just have the initial state be an empty string? Or does it have to be an object even though it's just a slice of the overall larger store object? If I can have it as a string, how do I make a new copy of the state each for each dispatch? The current `return {...state, ...action.data}` looks weird.

```
const initialState = ''

const filterText = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case constants.FILTER_CONTACTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.data
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default filterText
```

Answer (score 3):

The initial state can be a string, but then in every switch case it should also return a string.

When updating the state, you would not need to make a copy since your entire state is a string you would just return the new string.  If there are no changes, you would just return the old state.

```js
const initialState = ''

const filterText = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case constants.FILTER_CONTACTS:
      // return a string here, I'm assuming action.data is a string
      return action.data;
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default filterText
```

Hope this helps.